# http post using tcpclient in c# not working

Tags: c#, http-post, tcpclient

Hi i am trying to post to login page using tcpclient class . but it says 302 error. same thing i can do using webclient. please suggest where i am missing something.  **i have already achieved using webclient class. but i have asked to do at lower level. please suggest.**

**i have tried following**

```
 string sPost =  "POST  http://www.udupikrishnarestaurant.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"  +

 "Host: www.udupikrishnarestaurant.com\r\n" +

 "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +

 "Content-Length: 632\r\n" +

 "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n" +

 "Origin: http://www.udupikrishnarestaurant.com \r\n" +

"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n" +

"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36 \r\n" +

"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +

"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 \r\n" +

"Referer: http://www.udupikrishnarestaurant.com/ \r\n" +

"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n" +

"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n" +

"\r\n" +

"__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUKLTM0ODY4NTA5Mg9kFgRmD2QWAgIBDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGQCAQ8WAh4EVGV4dAUOMTgyLjY5LjEwOC4yMTFkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBQlidG5TdWJtaXQFCWJ0bkZvcmdvdCvBSicNzlFc1g4UTZeO96HhGK8T&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAr0HIr+WBkxh8yUckvqwLD4LqRynaTFa/5Hs7sApa3/2aRDGrH080vTDzQFiILKSswLyPw09K59GBb2rr9Ouzg352npSE7sRexHKIcGFqd4MCl0Pj8zqX34hAcL3lPJ6TZjemWCTRgEB59HPczIGVNwdjb4xzpKucCqKjegIpvFhjzmltaUM7aEAN+g9cP/m13MQ92x/wmKgUDwu+2MEZnSA5KkNGEzQJYQmFWkBWmYqAdLpnM=&ddlFloor=2&txtUserName=test&txtPassword=1234&btnSubmit.x=15&btnSubmit.y=3";


byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  string header = sPost;

  var client = new TcpClient();
  client.Connect("182.50.132.48", 80);

  // send request

  var stream = client.GetStream();
  var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
  var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

  streamWriter.Write(header);
  streamWriter.Flush();
  stream.Flush();

  // get response

  var response1 = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: 302 is a redirect. The full server response should tell you what you need to do

Comment: `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1` may cause a server to send a 302 redirect to an HTTPS url, try removing it.  Hard to see a case for doing this at the socket level, one of the frameworks built in HTTP clients is a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

302 is not an error. It is a request for redirection - the form tells you "go there instead", most likely as a result of your login attempt. `WebClient` handles the redirection, your client doesn't.

There's a lot of HTTP to implement. Unless this is purely an excercise, don't try to write your own HTTP client. Redirection is just the top of the iceberg.

Comment: is there way to achieve .. i want to see logged in page after submition.

Comment: i want to use low level to make response faster.

Comment: @marcskumar You think you're going to do a better job than the developers of the .NET BCL? Why? Are you planning to skip some parts of the process because they are unnecessary for your use case, or do you just assume that "lower level" means "faster"? `WebClient` doesn't even use `TcpClient`. Are you going to implement your own connection pooling? Caching? Have you considered `HttpClient`? And why do you want the response faster anyway? In what way is it inadequate? Are you making concurrent requests to the same host?

Comment: yes i am masking 6 to 7 request to same host. and when my site has lots of user webclient takes toomuch time to response.

Comment: i havent tried HttpClient. As i read article saying async operation is slow then sync.   http://cpratt.co/async-not-faster/

Comment: @marcskumar When you make multiple HTTP requests to the same host, they are queued - there's a limit defined by the HTTP specification. You can change this for `WebRequest` in your app.config. And oh god, you need to understand a lot more of the complexities to make judgements like that. Even the linked article doesn't say that - read it all, carefully, and understand it. Do you realize that *all* I/O in modern OS is asynchronous? The synchronous method calls are the wrappers, not vice versa. Your requests are obviously I/O bound - using asynchronous I/O is most likely the way to go. Profile.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. One more thing i would like to know. what should i use (httpwebrequest, WebClient or HttpClient) for best performance.  if i can save 1 ms as response time , it will be great for me. please suggest

Comment: @marcskumar I can't make any such suggestion. You have the use case, you have the test environment. Make a benchmark (and make sure it's a good benchmark) and figure out what's the best approach yourself. There's no general answer to "what to use for best performance" - and performance usually isn't the only important thing. What about security, correctness, error handling, flexibility, scope? If you want the absolute fastest way to get a response, that's "already have the response in advance". This is why we have caching, after all :)

Comment: If you want the absolute fastest way to get a response, that's "already have the response in advance". This is why we have caching, after all :)

i am sorry for my poor knowledge. but i dont understand how to have response in advance.
i have 6 post, each one is dependent on previous response. ie : suppose first request is made and for second request i need to wait for first  to response. so how to achieve advance response. i have session cookie in each request also.

Comment: I recorded fiddler time :

Overall Elapsed: 0:00:34.823

34 second for 1 request when there are thousand user on site.

Comment: @marcskumar If it takes that long, it most likely has nothing to do with your client code. The server simply can't take the load. The best thing you can do is have a separate asynchronous workflow for each of your users, and run as many as works in parallel. But the server is still going to be the bottleneck. As for having the response already, there's no general advice you can get. Perhaps the site has a public API you can use; perhaps you can avoid waiting for the response in some cases, or skip a request altogether; perhaps you can coöperate with the site instead of hacking on it.

Comment: @marcskumar Don't forget that once you're doing many concurrent requests, individual latencies don't matter much unless either the client or the server handles concurrency badly. That's where `await` really shines, and `HttpClient` gives you a nice and simple API to do exactly what you want :)